# Where should I begin when building a full-duplex Client/Server software?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I'm looking forward to roll out a simple server/client software, just to understand this field a little better.

So, as the title says, with what and where should I begin when building a full-duplex Client and Server software?

I'm looking to build it with C#, probably, but yeah, any language will cut it since I'm more interested in algorithms and simple implementations.

Last but not least, targeted mainly for working with TCP, but possible that I'll want to expand for specific data types later on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TCP and data types are different things. Try to make the communication as loose as possible. Define an abstract transport layer that can be implemented using TCP, but by dropping files in directory just as well. For the content, you can serialize data into XML or JSON. Making your application only slightly dependent on both the transport method and the protocol/data format user, is one of the greater challenges of Client/Server and N-Tier programming.

Comment: @GolezTrol, I'm aware of that TCP and data types are different things. I meant with that, that for some data types, I'll be looking for a more suited protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just building such a thing myself, and I think [socket.io](http://socket.io/) is great framework for full-duplex server-client event-driven communication. But it is node.js, not C#. On the other hand, you can write client in a browser and server in the same language as the client; moreover, node.js is specialized in "doing networking right", so you can learn things like non-blocking IO as well.

Comment: The part about "doing networking right", good thing you have that in quotes. Everybody seems to be doing everything right, except, it's only right for them.

Comment: Quoted Ryan Dahl, the author, as heard in one of videos out there. But I'd say in this case that it is not far from the truth, as he is really trying to push the single-thread, non-blocking io way and many (not all) high-performing networking apps (nginx) are built upon non-blocking io as the core idea.

Answer (score 3):

I absolutely agree with use of WCF from the previous answers.  That will definitely handle the server side of this interaction.  Code Project also has a lot of good examples of client/server interactions.  Check out something like [A TCP/IP Server written in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/tcpserverall.aspx).

To answer your question about cross-platform, I've used WCF to connect to and interact with Java, .NET and Objective-C clients, so I think you're safe there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C#/.NET I would recommend you use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx).

You can host this file on either a web server, or do self-hosting and host it inside of a standalone application.  Most of mine have been run through standard applications.

For information on full duplex services go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx).

I know there's a lot of information in both of those pages, but it's a fairly broad question! :)

Answer (score 2):

Start with [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx).

- Create a new Windows Service. That's your server.
- Create a winforms/wpf app/console app. That's your client.
- Create methods inside your service that will do some job.
- Call those methods from your client and print some results to the user.

Comment: Not cross-platform, more like, cross operating system, and what about dedicated ones?

Comment: @Tom: Not sure about it. If you want to stick to C#, but produce cross-platform, take a look at [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29). What do you mean by "*dedicated*" OS?

Comment: Wasn't meant dedicated OS, but a dedicated server.

Comment: @Tom: I think you're confused here. A *[dedicated server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedicated_hosting_service)* is a hosting server (a **machine**) on Internet that is only rented to you. When I say "*Create a new Windows Service. That's your server.*", what I call *server* is only an **application**. It differs from a winforms app or a console app *mainly* because it can be start without any user logged on the machine (and others reasons - not relevant here).

Comment: Maybe, maybe... With dedicated server I meant a server that runs something like 24/7, therefore has to be from ground up optimized, fast etc. But yeah, will look into WCF. Thanks! :)